# iphone 6 size not recognized by website. css code need to be added

Tags: ios, css, html, responsive-design, iphone-6

I have a problem. Recently I noticed that  my website has a problem showing the text with iPhone 6 and 6+. the text is little bit out of margin in right. with the other phones it automatically resizes the screen and I am able to see the text fully. But in iPhone 6 I need to add some sort of code to the css file of my html5 website.can any one help me with this issue?

Comment: Try -webkit-text-size-adjust:100%; and see if it works for you

Comment: I think I need a code like this: I don't know what are the media size that should be added to my style.css file:  
@media only screen and ( max-width: 768px ) {

Comment: Is your website based on a framework...like, bootstrap, or you're doing it from scratch